# Writing C++ modules for node.js

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, socket.io

Can anyone can give me a very small framework example of how to impliment a c++ module in node.js?

Comment: Cloudkick was absorbed into Rackspace; the blog no longer exists... :(

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The repository at https://github.com/kkaefer/node-cpp-modules contains many small examples with lots of comments that show you how to create a module. In addition, there's a [presentation](http://kkaefer.github.com/node-cpp-modules/) (use left/right arrow keys) that goes into detail about C++ modules.

Comment: anything more recent?

Comment: A more recent resource: https://medium.com/@marcinbaraniecki/extending-node-js-with-native-c-modules-63294a91ce4